# Cannot convert string to char when iterating through a char array C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to replace every 2nd character of user entered text to a underscore. I have iterated through a character array but when I try to change a specific character using an index it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'String' to 'Char'.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
Char[] secondChar = enteredString.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < secondChar.Length; i += 2)
{
    secondChar[i] = "_";
}
Console.WriteLine(secondChar);
```

Comment: `"_"` is a string. `'_'` is a char.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, _Im trying to replace the 2nd character_, OP intentionaly uses index 1

Comment: Yeah, starting at 1 was intentional. I don't know how I blanked on the double quotes, thanks.

Comment: If you want to overkill it, use System.Linq: `var replaced = string.Join("",enteredString.Select( (ch,idx) => idx%2==1 ? '_': ch));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using double quotes which indicates a string. Use single quotes instead to indicate `char`.

```
secondChar[i] = '_';
```